# Optimise the filtering of a infinite string in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, optimization, big-o

I'm solving a problem in HackerRank, in which I have to count the number of letters `'a'` in the first `n` elements of an infinite string of repeating sequences, for example `"abc"` for `"abcabcabcabc..."`.

I have implemented the following function using list comprehensions:

```hs
repeatedString s n = length $ [x | x <- take (fromInteger n) (cycle s), x == 'a']
```

Where `s` is the repeating sequence and `n` is the number of elements to take from the infinite string.

But HackerRank complains that did not execute within time limits for some of the tests.

The questions are:

- What are the bottlenecks here?
- How can I determine them for similar occasions?
- Can you point to a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: Clarified function parameters.

Comment: I haven't seen the problem, but I guess that it includes some very large values of `n`. I don't think you can make this "direct" approach more efficient but surely you can simply use division to figure out the number of full cycles of `s` needed, multiply that by the number of `'a'`'s in `s`, and then just deal with the remainder directly.

Comment: Just count the numbers of `a` in a string, and then check how many times the string will occur in `n`.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about that approach, but was wondering if there was anything else to do with my first take. Thank you!

Comment: @DavSanchez: but that runs in *O(n)*. If *n* is huge, then that will take forever. There is not much of a bottleneck, it simply is a "naive" way to calculate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do *not* need to count the number of `a`s explicitly. What you can do is:

1. count the number of `'a'`s in `c`;
2. check how many times you make a *full* cycle of `s` (by dividing `n` by the length of `s`);
3. the calculate how many characters are emitted in the *last* (uncomplete) cycle of `s`;
4. count the number of `'a'`s in that part.
5. sum up the number of `'a'`s of the full cycles and the number of `'a'`s of the incomplete cycle.

The program thus looks like:

```
repeatedString :: String -> Int -> Int
repeatedString s n = (length (filter ('a' ==) s) * div n (length s)) + …
```

with `…` the part you still need to fill in that deals with the last (incomplete) cycle.

Even if `n` is huge, the algorithm will still run in *O(|s|)*.